# Data fetching Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm running this following API call and getting list to vhosts and passing to another API and getting some values, those works fine.

```
response = conn.get("/api/vhosts")
statistics = JSON.parse(response.body)

statistics.each do |vhosts|
  response1 = conn.get("/api/exchanges/#{vhosts["name"]}/direct_queue_exchange")
  statistics1 = JSON.parse(response1.body)
  statistics1.fetch("message_stats").fetch("publish_in_details").fetch("rate")    
end
```

sample output:

```
output -1 - {"error"=>"Object Not Found", "reason"=>"Not Found"}

output -2 - {"message_stats"=>{"publish_in_details"=>{"rate"=>0.0}, "publish_in"=>91, "publish_out_details"=>{"rate"=>0.0}, "publish_out"=>91}, "outgoing"=>[], "incoming"=>[], "user_who_performed_action"=>"user_122f5b58", "arguments"=>{}, "internal"=>false, "auto_delete"=>false, "durable"=>true, "type"=>"direct", "vhost"=>"vhost_2388ce36", "name"=>"direct_queue_exchange"}
    {"outgoing"=>[], "incoming"=>[], "user_who_performed_action"=>"user_d6b8f477", "arguments"=>{}, "internal"=>false, "auto_delete"=>false, "durable"=>true, "type"=>"direct", "vhost"=>"vhost_37892b86", "name"=>"direct_queue_exchange"}
```

I have ran into problem fetching values I want. For example in my code I'm fetching these values like "rate" and I'm getting this error: `key not found: "message_stats"` because some outputs doesn't contains keys that I'm looking

How can I ignore outputs like this `{"error"=>"Object Not Found", "reason"=>"Not Found"}`

Comment: huh? It's as simple as trying to fetch by `"error"` first. If a value with such key exists, then you don't try to fetch the rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question right, there're several way to do that:

In Ruby 2.3 and above (thanks to **@Steve Turczyn**)

```
statistics1.dig('message_stats', 'publish_in_details', 'rate')
```

Almost like yours, second parameter of `fetch` sets default value if the key wasn't found:

```
statistics1.fetch("message_stats", {}).fetch("publish_in_details", {}).fetch("rate", nil)
```

Or you can do something like that:

```
message_stats = statistics1['message_stats']
next unless message_stats

publish_in_details = message_stats['publish_in_details']
next unless publish_in_details

publish_in_details['rate']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the default option in `#fetch` to return an empty hash if the key isn't present.

```
statistics1.fetch("message_stats", ()).fetch("publish_in_details", {}).fetch("rate", nil)
```

Even simper would be the `#dig` method

```
statistics1.dig("message_stats", "publish_in_details", "rate")
```

If any keys are missing, `nil` is gracefully returned.

Comment: `dig` is a nice method, indeed. To mention, it works only in ruby 2.3 and above.

Comment: @nattfodd yes, in fact I think it would be nice if `nil` responded to `dig` as well... that way you wouldn't even need to worry about whether `statistics1` was a hash. I've done that monkey patch in some of my projects.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn  dig works like charm, then i'll filter data i need.
thanks steve.

Answer (score 0):

Other two also provide solution for your question, Below is description for same.

```
fetch(key_name) # get the value if the key exists, raise a KeyError if it doesn't
fetch(key_name, default_value) # get the value if the key exists, return default_value otherwise
```

So use below will solve your issue.

```
statistics1.fetch("message_stats", ()).fetch("publish_in_details", {}).fetch("rate", nil)
```

also you can check if error present or not, and then handle case accordingly.

```
if fetch("message_stats", false)
  statistics1.fetch("message_stats").fetch("publish_in_details").fetch("rate")
end
```